# Is there another way of converting a value entered by a user in an entry without using Convert?.... (Convert.ToDouble or Convert.ToInt)

Tags: xamarin, syncfusion

I am using syncfusion numeric textbox because I want the user to enter double value into the textbox. But when i use the ConvertToDouble or ToInt if it's null then it returns a value of 0. Is there any option I can use for conversion?

```
//from database
    public double rain1vol { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(3)]
    public double rain2vol { get; set; }

//user entered to database
Post post = new Post()
        {
          rain1vol = Convert.ToDouble(Sfrain1Entry.Value),
          rain2vol = Convert.ToDouble(Sfrain2Entry.Value),

       rain2vol = Sfrain2Entry.Value == null ? null : Convert.ToDouble(Sfrain2Entry.Value); 
//this is the line i've tried but has error
// no implicit conversion between null and int.

            // rain1vol = rain1Entry.Text,
            //rain2vol = rain2Entry.Text

        };
```

Comment: Why don't you check for empty and null before trying to convert? Post the code that you tried.

Comment: so if rain2vol == 0 then don't do Convert.ToDouble....?

Comment: Why would you want to return null into your database for these values? Would it not make sense to instead have a default value?

Comment: because if it's null or empty not zero, it wouldn't get entered in database.  There is switch if user picked only 1 to enter then only one value should be entered. but with this returning a zero, the 2nd entry(column) gets a value of zero entered in database then shows up in listview when i only want to show one column from the database because the user picked only 1 value to be entered.  Maybe im going to this the wrong way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use method `String.IsNullOrEmpty()`  to check the value  and `try- catch` to achieve this .

For example, you can do like this:

```
       var value = Sfrain1Entry.Text;

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            double result1;
            try
            {
                result1 = Convert.ToDouble(value);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The input is : " + result1);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else if (value.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The input is IsWhiteSpace...");
        }
        else {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The input is invalid...");
        }
```

Note:

1. You can use method `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` to filter the input data. 
   After that , you can use method `value.Trim().Length == 0` to verify if it is `whitespaces`.
2. You can adjust the code according your requirement.

Comment: yes but i would like it if it's white spaces don't do the convert... leave it as whitespaces.. if it's whitespace then it wouldnt go into database and show up on listview.